# How do I install an external Python package in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

Is it possible to install an external package in QGIS?
For example: Can I install ReportLab in order to create a plugin to make pdf reports?

Or Pandas. How can I install Pandas in QGIS Python library?

Comment: Go to the plugins manager and look for it there. If it's not there then you'll have to write/adapt your own, but those instructions would take several pages if you're not an adept programmer. Please give an indication of your programming ability.

Comment: I have knowledge of programming in python3x and PyQGIS and would like to adapt some scirpts to process spatial data so you can launch them from a button in QGIS, but I need to import certain libraries.

Comment: go right ahead, any library that has a python module can be co-imported (even arcpy). http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html has instructions on how to create a plugin. Unfortunately you are limited to python; QGIS source can be downloaded if you want to make your own version but that is strongly discouraged.

Comment: Am not sure if Reportlab and Pandas will install correctly on the python set that came with QGIS? However, I was able to install PySAL library on it, I wrote the steps I took here: http://umar-yusuf.blogspot.com.ng/2016/07/How-to-Install-Third-party-Python-Modules-in-QGIS-Windows.html

Comment: you can read the answers for this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141320/how-to-install-3rd-party-python-libraries-for-qgis-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

QGIS has no ability to install Python plugin dependencies. You need to notify user to install dependencies by itself or merge dependency code into your plugin.
There are limited number of Python modules shipped with QGIS under Linux/Windows (not sure with Mac OS X):

1. dateutil
2. httplib2
3. jinja2
4. markupsafe
5. nose2
6. pygments
7. pyspatialite
8. pytz
9. siz
10. yaml