# install python packages for qgis?

Tags: qgis, python

I need the twisted framework (Python) for a qgis plugin on Windows 7.
I installed it with the pip installer.
When I want to start the plugin it doesn't find twisted.
When I start a python interpreter in the cmd.exe twisted can be imported.

this is my path variable: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\BIN;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27;

twisted is installed inside C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

How should I install a python package when I want to use it inside QGIS?

Comment: look at [Using 3rd party libraries on QGIS (Windows)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141320/using-3rd-party-libraries-on-qgis-windows/141358#141358)