# Trouble installing Rasterio module for python 2.7 on windows

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, rasterio

Can anyone please explain to me in step by step instructions how to install **rasterio** with Python 2.7 on Windows. I have Windows 8 and have tried information on [Link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rasterio)

I have installed all the dependencies mentioned and when I try to run the following command on command prompt:

```
$ rasterio-0.24.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

It displays an error:

```
rasterio-0.24.1-cp27-none-win_amd64 is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I have tried all the binaries given at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rasterio but none has worked.

It's installation requires GDAL also and when I try any of the GDAL binaries it gives the same error message as that for rasterio but nevertheless I have installed GDAL with  OSGeo4W installer. Now how do I go about installing rasterio? Please suggest something.

Comment: You use Python 2.7 and you are trying to install the version for Python 3.4 (cp34)

Comment: Sorry, I just gave an example and mistakenly that of python 3.0 but I have tried all the binaries that are compatible with python 2.7 and none worked. I'll make the changes in the question. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Is your python 64bit or 32bit?

Comment: Read carefully the text at the top of Gohlke's index page and also this https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#installing-from-wheels that he links to.

Comment: For complete beginners on Windows trying to get it to work inside QGIS: [This](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141320/how-to-install-3rd-party-python-libraries-for-qgis-on-windows) might be useful.

Comment: In case this could help linux users, consider the following command line to automatically install rasterio and dependencies: pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple rasterio (see https://anaconda.org/pypi/rasterio)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/107743)

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to get past this problem by systematically going through all of the supporting requirements for rasterio.

One of the key things that helped was:

pip install wheel --upgrade

However also, I touched many many of the other modules (upgrading GDAL, numpy, click and Cython ) before finally getting to the point where

pip install rasterio-0.24.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl would finally work for me.

I had success using this method, but then also ran into some later problems to which I am now searching for answers!