# How to install 3rd party python libraries for QGIS without OSGeo4W on Windows?

Tags: qgis, python

I want to install pip package in QGIS. I have tried the standard windows installation from Windows command line as explanined in pip site, but still can not import pip from QGIS Python console. I have read the following question but I use standalone installation for QGIS and have no OSGeo4W installation.

[How to install 3rd party python libraries for QGIS on Windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141320/how-to-install-3rd-party-python-libraries-for-qgis-on-windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the answer in the post, you have [QGIS Standalone and the Python Modules](http://quantumofgis.blogspot.be/2014/11/qgis-standalone-and-python-modules.html)