# Is there any list of Python packages bundled with QGIS 3 installation on Windows?

Tags: qgis, python, installation

We currently solving the [problem of dependcies](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311726/adding-missing-python-packages-to-qgis-plugin) of our plugin. Since we want to have user-friendly installation (inexperienced users), one of the possible solution is drop some used packages in favour the ones that are built-in in QGIS 3 (on Windows).

That leads me to this question: Which are the packages? Is there any list of these packages that are bundled with QGIS installation on Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if a list exists but you could install it and generate one by noting all the .py files and folders located in the install `\\Python\lib` directory:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS {version}\apps\Python{version}\lib
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)! I don't use any windows machine, but if there is no other option I will definitely try check this on some PC with windows. But I am afraid that is not so sustainable solution for me (for future developments, new versions of QGIS and so on)

Answer (score 8):

One can try the following commands directly in the [QGIS's Python Console](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/python_console.html) to get more information regarding Python packages bundled with QGIS.

To list all Python modules:

```py
help("modules")
```

To search for modules whose name or summary contain the string *"xml"*, type this:

```py
help("modules xml")
```

Enter any module name to get more help, e.g. *"yaml"*.

```py
help("yaml")
```

*Note:* that there are some drawbacks to this approach, including:

- If there are a lot of installed packages, this method can take a long time to import each module before it can search that module’s path for sub-modules.
- Python modules that have code outside of an if `__name__ == "__main__":` code block, and if user input is expected, may cause the code to enter an infinite loop or hang.
- Module versions are not included

Answer (score 8):

You can also list the packages installed by QGIS installation after a fresh installation using `pip` on OSGeo Shell:

```
python -m pip list
```