Detecting missing credentials programmatically in QGIS Plugin
I am creating a Python plugin that loads two layers, a layer for everyone and an "admin" layer. I want to keep the admin password out of QGIS, so I plan to use a pgpass file.
So from the perspective of QGIS, the connection either works or not. The default behavior is to prompt for the password on error, but I want to detect that the connection does not work and then not show the layer at all, without user feedback.
Is there a way to detect that a connection fails without installing additional packages, or at least a way to suppress the DB credential prompts?
Example code:
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("db-server", "5432", "dbname", "username", None)

uri.setDataSource("schema", "table", "geom")
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "My Admin Layer", "postgres")

if layer.isValid():
    if (instance := QgsProject.instance()) is not None:
        instance.addMapLayer(layer, False)


You could create a connection using the psycopg2 library, which is preinstalled with QGIS, and see if the connection and the table query is successful with your supplied credentials. If it was successful, proceed with the QGIS DB Connection
import psycopg2

connection_params = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': '5432',
    'dbname': 'postgres',
    'user': 'postgres',
    'password': 'mypassword'
}

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(**connection_params)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    schema_name = 'public'
    table_name = 'data'
    query = f'SELECT 1 FROM "{schema_name}"."{table_name}" LIMIT 1'
    cursor.execute(query)
    cursor.fetchone()
    print(f"access to table '{table_name}' confirmed")
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)


Thanks for you answer! I was also thinking about psycopg2, but I couldn't determine if it came preinstalled or another plugin installed it separately. Is there a list of what comes preinstalled with QGIS?

And from what I understand, psycopg2 can use the .pgpass file so the password can be dropped from the connection_params.

Maybe this helps:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311875/is-there-any-list-of-python-packages-bundled-with-qgis-3-installation-on-windows

I saw that one, but I think it will show the all installed packages (pre and manual) if I don't nuke QGIS beforehand.
