# Automatically Installing Dependencies for QGIS Plugin

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I recently uploaded my plugin to the QGIS Plugin Repository. The problem I'm encountering is that my plugin relies on the openpyxl library, which is not bundled with QGIS. Consequently, users encounter a 'module not found' error when attempting to install the plugin. I would like to know how I can automate the installation of the openpyxl library on users' PCs

Comment: Have you tried some of the other suggestions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/196002/development-of-a-plugin-which-depends-on-an-external-python-library

Comment: No I didn't. I think the "try: import package except: ..." solution looks good, Should I include it in my plugin main python file, where the code is written?

Comment: Yes, the main part.

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto Thank you so much, it worked