# No module named requests

Tags: qgis-plugins, windows, windows-7, request

I'm developing a QGIS Plugin with python.
I need to do a request to a REST server. But when I try to use request module "No module named requests" error displayed.

requests module is installed in my system, but I don't know why QGIS doesn't detect it.

What can I do?

My SO is Windows 7 Ultimate, and QGIS version installed is 2.14.3

Comment: Ignore QGIS for a moment. What happens when you do a `import requests` using a python command line?

Comment: In a python comand line I can import requests without problem, but in QGis python console the error is:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/****/***/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named requests`
Same as plugin error.

Comment: Are you sure the commad line Python is in the same place as the one QGIS uses? On windows, QGIS has its own python version, while there may be another in your PATH as well to be used outside QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

You need install the missing library in the qgis path.

[image]

And that is installed correctly,on the osgeo4W shell ,write this `pip list`.

[image]

And ,after start qgis and check that is intalled correctly,with `import requests`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `requests` package isn't installed for the python instance used by QGIS. Please see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141320/how-to-install-3rd-party-python-libraries-for-qgis-on-windows) for tips on how to install python packages for QGIS.

Comment: When I write 'pip list' requests appears in list. But in QGis requests can´t import.