# Installing Geographiclib with QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geographiclib

I am trying to install the package "geographiclib-1.20.tar.gz" Referring to a previous post to install 3rd Party libraries [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141320/how-to-install-3rd-party-python-libraries-for-qgis-on-windows). I ran OSGeo4W Shell and tried to use pip. This is the error message I am getting. What am I doing wrong ?
[image]

How do I install the setuptools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotcha !! The geographiclib-1.20.tar.gz package needs to be unzipped , so that there's a folder called geographiclib-1.20 is created with a file setup.py inside it. Run OsGeo4w Shell as administrator and use the cd to go the geographiclib-1.20 folder. Now type the command `python setup.py install`

that's it. This will install the library in the correct folder `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages`