# to be able to use mysql-connector-python inside QGIS python script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, mysql

I am creating python script in QGIS python console to be able to connect to mysql db and manipulate data (retrieve from db, generate shapefile and show it as a layer).
I tried to install mysql connector from OSGeo4w shell:
pip install mysql-connector-python but it fails with error:

C:>pip install mysql-connector-python
Collecting mysql-connector-python
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\packages\urllib
3\util\ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the S
NI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform.
 This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can ca
use validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve t
his. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security
.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\packages\urllib
3\util\ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not ava
ilable. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause c
ertain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to
solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/s
ecurity.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python
 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mysql-connector-python

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Almost the same solution: [how-to-install-3rd-party-python-libraries-for-qgis-on-windows](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141320/how-to-install-3rd-party-python-libraries-for-qgis-on-windows/144306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occured probably to my proxy limitations.
But my problem was solved by another way:

1. pip install wheel (ussing osgeo4w command shell).
2. download wl files from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
mysqlclient-1.3.10-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
and install them
pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
pip install mysqlclient-1.3.10-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

3. see https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/connecting-to-mysql-using-python for the python code example to deal with db connections.

My test example is:

```
def doQuery( conn ) :
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute( "SELECT name, vendor FROM t" )

    for bname,bvendor in cur.fetchall() :
        print bname,bvendor

import MySQLdb
myConnection = MySQLdb.connect(host=<host_ip>, user=db_user, passwd=db_pass, db=db_schema_or_db_instance )
doQuery( myConnection )
myConnection.close()
```