# How to install an in house package from local directory in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, installation

I need to install a private package which is in my local directory to the QGIS Python environment. I can install it to my conda environmnet by defining the local directory path as channel. How do I install in QGIS Python environment?

Note - I am creating a QGIS plugin which uses services from the in-house package.

The answer to [Installing 3rd party python libraries for QGIS on Windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141320) does not work for me as I am not installing Python packages.

Comment: It sounds like the package you want to install is a conda package? Does it have any dependencies on other conda packages? It might not be the direction you want to go, but there is a qgis package on [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qgis). You could create a new conda environment with qgis and the custom package you need.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for this idea! It worked like a charm.