# Filter parent layer with child table in 1-N relation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, filter, relates

I have a layer with a related (1-N) table and I need to filter the parent layer with values of the child table.

I have tried with the Query builder of the Provider feature filter in the layer properties, but I can't see any way to do that.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Thanks for answer @KadirŞahbaz, I reasked the question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141320/installing-3rd-party-python-libraries-for-qgis-on-windows).