# Upgrading pip on QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, python, pip

I'm trying to run the Aequilibrae package on QGIS 3.16.14 (on windows)and to do so, it seems that I need to update my pip package.
I tried the command :
`-m pip install --upgrade pip`
on the integrated python console, but I had an invalid syntax error pointing to the first 'p' of 'pip'.
Since it was the recommended command and I am very new to the python console, I have to admit I'm a bit lost...

Comment: You don't run `-m pip install --upgrade pip` from a python console, you run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` from a command prompt

Comment: thanks for this tip. I tried it but now have a SSL error trying to run it. ('WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.')

Answer (score 1):

you need to run the upgrade from osgeo4w shell. I tested it on my machine (win 10 Qgis 3.16.13) and it seems to work.

To find the shell two ways :

1. (if you are on windows) you use windows indexation by pressing windows button on your keyboard and typing the first letters of `OSGeo4W`, it should appear and you can launch it
2. you go to your Qgis installation directory and you find `OSGeo4W.bat`, you double click it and you launch the shell
3. if you are on another OS, you need to find this shell too, but I dont know where, probably in your installation directory as well

(if you type `python` in the shell, it should start the interpreter for the python distributed with Qgis, you can exit it by typing `exit()`)

Then, you can run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.
 In my case I had warnings 
`WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.9.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'myOwnPersonalPath\Python\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location. Successfully installed pip-21.3.1`

If you then go to the python console in qgis you can check the version by typing : 
`import pip` 
`pip.__version__`
it should be the upgraded one

see [Installing 3rd party python libraries for QGIS on Windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141320/how-to-install-3rd-party-python-libraries-for-qgis-on-windows) for more details