# Install Python library in QGIS as non-administrator

Tags: python, pyqgis, installation, osgeo4w

I would like to install the Python library in QGIS, but I have no administrator rights.
Unfortunately, each solution found refers to the simplest installation via osGeo4W, which requires running as an administrator:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPMHhgR-r7E&ab_channel=GEO2004
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94W51WuDKzA&ab_channel=UmarYusufhttps://landscapearchaeology.org/2018/installing-python-packages-in-qgis-3-for-windows/

Even if I choose the other option by typing python code in the console like:

```
 import subprocess
 subprocess.check_call(['python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'openpyxl'])
```

[Installing 3rd party python libraries for QGIS on Windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141320/installing-3rd-party-python-libraries-for-qgis-on-windows)

it will still throw the

> Error13: Permission denied

With respect to this situation, I am wondering about the completely manual way of providing the Python library to the QGIS root folder, for instance via simply copying the files from other root directories (i.e. from IDLE Python, where I could install everything without the problems).

Is there any way, which would allow w me to expand the Python library in QGIS without admin rights?

UPDATE:

As per the hint below:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-openpyxl-in-python-on-windows/

I've entered this link and followed the steps, but it looks like it's still not valid for QGIS.
I've chosen the Folium library as an example. The installation has proceeded very well, although it's still not recognized in PyQGIS.

[image]

**UPDATE II:**

Unfortunately none of the hints below work.

Regarding the first one, the situation looks like this:

[image]

The second one presents below:

[image]

Maybe I have different path or something?

Comment: Does it work if you add `'--user'`?

Comment: You can use source code of the library as part of your python plugin

Comment: How to find the code like this?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-openpyxl-in-python-on-windows/ - the second method

Comment: It works fine, but only in  Windows-wide environments, and not particularly for QGIS. I will update the question and explain.

Comment: Save "Untitled-0.py" file to some "YOUR FOLDER". Copy folium folder to "YOUR FOLDER" too.  Replace first string in "Untitled-0.py" with "from .folium.folium import *".

Comment: Unfortunately you will get a bunch of new modules to install...

Comment: 1. Note that QGIS uses it's own python installation. 2. If I run the setup.exe from Osgeo4w I don't need admin rights. Many python packages can be installed from there. 3. Pip installed by osgeo also can be used, but if a package uses a C-compiler things can get complicated.

Answer (score 11):

Since you don't have admin privileges, when you install a package using QGIS Python Console/Editor as follows, it is installed to `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming` folder.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'folium'])
```

[image]

Therefore, if you add this folder to the path in your script, you can import the package.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages")

import folium
```

[image]

Comment: Updated my question, as it's still not resolved. Maybe my path is different? I've downloaded the folium library from pypi and stored in this path manually, but QGIS cannot see it either.

Comment: I don't know. The code worked when I tried using a restricted user account. Did you manage to install it using OSGeo Shell?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Anyway, I can accept your answer, because I guess there's something wrong with my laptop/path/firewall. I don't know. At least I know the path, from which QGIS takes the libraries. I will fiddle with it more. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I prefer that you do not accept the answer. The problem may be different and someone else can provide a solution.

Comment: OK. I tried something and I think I found a workaround for it and will paste the answer soon.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the earlier answer, I found another workaround for the issue in the case, when you might have a situation like mine (read Update II).

The steps are:

1. **Download your Python library** from the pypi.org website

   [image]
2. Convert files optionally to .zip extension, i.e. by using the https://cloudconvert.com/gz-to-zip
3. Copy the .zip content to the following directory:

   ```
   C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages
   ```
4. Run the following code:

   ```
   import sys

   sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sgp4-2.21")

   import sgp4
   ```

In the `sys.path.append`, remember to **use the correct folder** with your python library as it appears in your zip file.

[image]

Then everything should be alright.