# Installing H3 for QGIS 3.22 on Windows

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, h3

First of all, I installed the plugin of H3 in QGIS 3.22.16
Then I installed the library of h3 in Windows as explained in the tutorials for Python.

```
pip install h3
```

I got the successfully installed in PowerShell (and also uninstalled it and tried in VSCode) and then when I opened QGIS again nothing happened.
I also tried downloading the script and opening it from QGIS processing tools but I keep getting the pop-up oh help for installing.

I'm using Python 3.8

Comment: You need to install `h3` library via OSGeo4W Shell like here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141320/installing-3rd-party-python-libraries-for-qgis-on-windows